# Is there a 'last occurrence' version of charindex?

Tags: sql, sybase

I have a table of `varchar`s that can take the form of `"Hi","Hello","Greetings"` and so forth; it is effectively multiple translations for the same message, depending on length.  I want to get the last of these for each.

Currently I have the following code to get the first one:

```
rtrim(ltrim(str_replace(case when charindex(',', m.Message) > 0 then left(m.Message, charindex(',', m.Message)-1) else m.Message end, '"', '')))
```

But I am using a context, where the longest versions (which are usually the last ones) would be preferred.  So I wonder if I there was a version of `charindex` that took the *last* occurrence instead of the first, because then I could keep it a one liner as now, as it is part of a `select`.

Comment: You could try a double `reverse`. It's a bit costly, but could work for your needs.  Like the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851650/sql-server-2005charindex-starting-from-the-end