# SQL server query: remove text between the last index of two characters?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

### The Problem

I have a field that stores file keys, such as:

`dev/application/document_type_name/document 12345-67890_123.pdf`

I need to select the key without the number on the end so the value looks like:

`dev/application/document_type_name/document 12345-67890_.pdf`

### Potential Strategy

It's been a while since I've done T-SQL but coming from the .NET side I think the general strategy would be:

- Get the last index of an underscore character
- Get the last index of the period character.
- Replace the value between those two characters with a blank.

In C#, I think it would be something like:

```
var test = "dev/application/document_type_name/document 12345-67890_123.pdf"
var indexOfUnderscore = test.LastIndexOf("_");
var indexOfPeriod = test.LastIndexOf(".");
var textToReplace = subtring(indexOfUnderscore + 1, indexOfPeriod -1);
var output = test.Replace(textToReplace, String.Empty);
```

Notes:

- Every key will have that Format
- The length of the value between the underscore and the period may be different (could be 1, 12345, etc.
- the end result should keep the underscore and period

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Yes; posted from mobile so wasn't able to give detailed examples. Will be updating soon but putting out a fire at the moment.

Comment: [This will help] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851650/sql-server-2005charindex-starting-from-the-end

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
select left(@s,len(@s)-charindex('_',REVERSE(@s)))+'_.pdf'
```

where `@s` is your string.
Or if the file extension can change

```
select left(@s,len(@s)-charindex('_',REVERSE(@s))+1) 
     + right(@s,charindex('.',REVERSE(@s)))
```

Comment: WOW you're good. This appears to work perfectly, and you added the part about extensions changing before I could even comment to ask about it. :) What a great, succinct solution. Thank you!